# how to get customer id from mysql and then to store it in a session variable to use the session variable in another file to retrieve information

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I am new to PHP.
I've made a login page and a register page, and I want to store the customer id after successful login or registration on my session variable so that I can use a session variable later in my cart file to retrieve cart details of that customer.The customer id is autoincrementing on the table so I don't take the input from the customer for the customer id.
here are the codes

login.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Naruto97","musicgallery");

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
    $password=md5($password);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM LoginCredentials WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        //Want to store the customer in session variable here after successful login
        header("location:home.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message']= "Email/Password combination Incorrect";
    }
}

   ?>
```

register.php:

```
     <?php
session_start();
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Naruto97","musicgallery");

if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])){

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password2']);

    if($password==$password2){
        $password=md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO LoginCredentials(Username,email,password) VALUES('$username','$email','$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        //Want to store the customer_id here in the session variable after successful registration
        header("location:home.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message']="The passwords do not match";

    }
}
   ?>
```

cart.php:

```
     <?php
       session_start();
       $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Naruto97","musicgallery");
       if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])){
         if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
           $album_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['hidden_name']);
           $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['hidden_price']);
           $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['quantity']);
           //$customer_id= $_SESSION['customer_id'];
           $sql = "INSERT INTO cart(album_name,price,quantity,customer_id) VALUES('$album_name','$price','$quantity','$customer_id')";
          mysqli_query($db, $sql);
          echo "<script>alert('Added to cart')</script>";
          echo "<script>window.location('kpop.php')</script>";
          } 
          else
          {
             echo "<script>alert('Please Login')</script>";
             echo "<script>window.location('kpop.php')</script>";
          }
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Are you able to use the set SESSION variables like $_SESSION['email]?

Comment: you want the customerid when the user registers?

Comment: Yes, $_SESSION['email'] is working. I have stored the $email (which is an input from the customer) on to this Session variable. But customer id gets stores after customer registers, I need to retrieve it after he registers and store in a SESSION VARIABLE. And also after he logins, as you can see in the code- I store the email id to the Session variable, same way I want to store the customer_id

Comment: $customerId=mysqli_insert_id($db); 
This will give you the inserted customerid

Answer (score 0):

To get the last insertid in mysqli use:-

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO cart(album_name,price,quantity,customer_id) VALUES('$album_name','$price','$quantity','$customer_id')";
      mysqli_query($db, $sql);


$_SESSION['customerId']=mysqli_insert_id($db);//gets the last inserted customerid from db
```

For any further reference you can check in this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).